# Python JSON to CSV not working

Tags: python, json, csv

I am having trouble to convert json to CSV. 
I am kinda new to JSON parsing. All I want is to get from
my JSON some "pretty" csv. So I can have data that I can read.

I am trying

```
f = csv.writer(open('data.csv', 'w+', encoding='utf-8', newline=''))
for item in json_head:
    f.writerow(item)
```

but all I get in `data.csv` is

```
d,a,t,a
i,n,c,l,u,d,e,d
l,i,n,k,s
m,e,t,a
```

Json template that's in documentation looks like this

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "string",
    "id": "string",
    "attributes": {
      "createdAt": "string",
      "duration": 0,
      "gameMode": "string",
      "patchVersion": "string",
      "shardId": "string",
      "stats": {},
      "tags": {},
      "titleId": "string"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "assets": {
        "data": [
          {
            "type": "string",
            "id": "string"
          }
        ]
      },
      "rosters": {
        "data": [
          {
            "type": "string",
            "id": "string"
          }
        ]
      },
      "rounds": {},
      "spectators": {}
    },
    "links": {
      "schema": "string",
      "self": "string"
    }
  },
  "included": [
    null
  ],
  "links": {
    "first": "string",
    "previous": "string",
    "self": "string",
    "next": "string"
  },
  "meta": {}
}
```

And part of real JSON I received via API looks like this

```
{"data":
    {"type":"match","id":"bdd8b91c-8866-47f1-b5ee-45de4163d3ad","attributes":{"createdAt":"2018-04-02T12:16:33Z","duration":1806,"gameMode":"squad-fpp","patchVersion":"","shardId":"pc-eu","stats":null,"tags":null,"titleId":"bluehole-pubg"},"relationships":{"assets":{"data":[{"type":"asset","id":"2609ba26-3674-11e8-b808-0a586466e20b"}]},
    "rosters":{"data":[
    {"type":"roster","id":"80a9215c-bed1-4c11-8ff7-e4c9d643befa"},
    {"type":"roster","id":"1457bd01-80f9-45e3-b98f-aa9ea946f6b2"}]},
    "rounds":{"data":[]},"spectators":{"data":[]}},"links":{"schema":"","self":"https://api.playbattlegrounds.com/shards/pc-eu/matches/bdd8b91c-8866-47f1-b5ee-45de4163d3ad"}},
    "included":[
    {"type":"participant","id":"f0d889c7-49e7-4c83-ac0b-d7f23d13e09f","attributes":{"actor":"","shardId":"pc-eu","stats":{"DBNOs":3,"assists":0,"boosts":2,"damageDealt":253.554047,"deathType":"byplayer","headshotKills":1,"heals":0,"killPlace":4,"killPoints":1182,"killPointsDelta":48.6543655,"killStreaks":0,"kills":4,"lastKillPoints":0,"lastWinPoints":0,"longestKill":5,"mostDamage":0,"name":"TheFieryArrow","playerId":"account.e951c5cf324d4153850fb411a13f4e8d","revives":0,"rideDistance":4288.21143,"roadKills":0,"teamKills":0,"timeSurvived":1215,"vehicleDestroys":0,"walkDistance":1508.55408,"weaponsAcquired":0,"winPlace":15,"winPoints":1113,"winPointsDelta":7.15782833}}},
    {"type":"participant","id":"5c26da97-6733-49d4-8a56-5dc7513e3c77","attributes":{"actor":"","shardId":"pc-eu","stats":{"DBNOs":0,"assists":0,"boosts":0,"damageDealt":64.68,"deathType":"byplayer","headshotKills":0,"heals":0,"killPlace":93,"killPoints":1111,"killPointsDelta":-14.2245054,"killStreaks":0,"kills":0,"lastKillPoints":0,"lastWinPoints":0,"longestKill":0,"mostDamage":0,"name":"Ritter-Sport","playerId":"account.f704b21b861b4c649ec56a0d688171c8","revives":0,"rideDistance":0,"roadKills":0,"teamKills":0,"timeSurvived":142,"vehicleDestroys":0,"walkDistance":43.5367622,"weaponsAcquired":0,"winPlace":28,"winPoints":1220,"winPointsDelta":-19.1033173}}},
```

For beginning it's enough if there is a way to get data from specific elements, for me those are these elements `"type":"participant"`
And I would expect tabular data like this

```
ID                                    |DBNOs | assists | boosts | othercolumns from "stats"
f0d889c7-49e7-4c83-ac0b-d7f23d13e09f  | 3    |   0     |   2    |
5c26da97-6733-49d4-8a56-5dc7513e3c77  | 0    |   0     |   0    |
```

I know I could hardcode some code to parse it, I am just looking for every possibility.

Thanks

Comment: what would your expected CSV look like?

Comment: I just edited question, you can see there json template

Comment: JSON stores arbitrarily shaped data, CSV is specifically (usually) for tabular data (a table with distinct columns). There isn't any one particular, good way to convert the JSON schema you provided into a CSV table. Please give an example of the kind of CSV output you expect for the given real JSON data you provided.

Comment: @PatrikPlecho If all you want to get is the data printed in an easy-to-read way, ask that instead of "how to get to CSV". There are actually good answers to that questions, but CSV seems like a very strange and potentially impossible thing to ask for in this particular situation

Comment: e.g., `from pprint import pformat; open('data.json', 'w+').write(pformat(json_head))`

Comment: @scnerd I did not realize the way the JSON works. I did edit question, I hope it is easy to understand.

Comment: I think the correct answer is "hardcode some code to parse it", there's no simpler way to extract out the data you're looking for. JSON isn't tabular, and if you want CSV out, you need to manually write the code to extract the data you're interested in into a tabular format. The JSON data you give is multi-tiered with embedded lists, and you want data from multiple levels... You can iterate through dictionaries using `dict.items()` to get tuples of key-value pairs. I really don't know what else to offer to help you out here. There's no magic bullet that does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
for item in json_head:
    f.writerow(item)
```

it only reads the keys within your json, which are then passed as a string to the `writerow` method, which treats it as an iterable of characters and writes individual characters to csv.

Instead, try doing this:

```
for item in json_head:
    f.writerow([item, json_head[item])
```

Comment: Or `for index, item in enumerate(json_head)`

Comment: The result in final file looked like
    `"item" : "plain JSON as string"
 
    "item2" : "plain JSON as string"`

Comment: @PatrikPlecho Alright. what would your expected CSV look like for the 
 data in the question? Json keys can be arbitary, and there isn't a way of knowing if they are all going to be common across the board.